# How can I format a time / duration in MomentJS so it is in Hours, Minutes and Seconds

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm just using momentJS for the first time and I love it. However I have been using it for less than a day and I have a problem and I can't seem to find a solution, so perhaps someone here can help. In my Angular application I have a method that takes two dates as timestamps / numbers (sorry if my terminology is wrong) and this should output the difference between these two dates.

I have the following function:

```
   /**
   * Method that takes two timestamps and returns the number of hours between the dates
   * @param to - timestamp
   * @param from - timestamp
   */
  public calculateDuration(to: number, from: number): string {
    return moment(from).diff(moment(to), 'HHmmss');
  }
```

now suppose I try to call that function like so:

`this.calculateDuration(156578488067,1565955844201);`

I get an output of -170963523. What I am really looking for is a way for the output to be ***{{X}} Hours, {{Z}} Minutes and {{Y}} seconds***. Using 'HHmmss' isn't correct. But playing around with the different formats listed at https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/01-format/ isn't getting me anywhere. Can someone please help me understand or tell me how I can achieve the desired output using momentJS?

Comment: What is 156578488067 supposed to represent? As milliseconds since the ECMAScript epoch, it's 1974-12-18T06:01:28.067Z. Is that what you're expecting? 1565955844201 is 2019-08-16T11:44:04.201Z.

Comment: i'm just going to leave [this](https://github.com/Pamblam/protodate#intro) here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easily done with momentjs

```js
let from = 156578488067,
    to =  1565955844201;
    
let d = moment.duration(to - from);
console.log(`${d.years()} Years ${d.months()} Months ${d.days()} Days ${d.hours()} Hours ${d.minutes()} Minutes ${d.seconds()}.${d.milliseconds()} Seconds`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js" integrity="sha256-H9jAz//QLkDOy/nzE9G4aYijQtkLt9FvGmdUTwBk6gs=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could subtract directly instead of `diff`:

```js
/**
 * Method that takes two timestamps and returns the number of hours between the dates
 * @param to - timestamp
 * @param from - timestamp
 */
function calculateDuration(to, from) {
  return moment(to - from).tz('America/New_York').format('HH [Hours,] mm [Minutes and] ss [seconds]');
}

console.log(calculateDuration(156578488067, 1565955844201));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```

Comment: For me this gives 4:17:23 which seems wildly inaccurate.

Comment: @RobG yes I don't think subtraction is the way to go